# How can I modify my jQuery so that the parent's rel attribute is used?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

My jQuery code below is not very reusable. As you see in the document ready, I am not taking the rel attribute value directly from the parent (not sure how to). Instead, I have to be specific as to what parent's rel I take the value from. Any help is appreciated.

And here is a link to a jsfiddle I just set up: http://jsfiddle.net/RXb5K/

```
        function keyToolTip() {
            $('.educoreres_key').mouseover(function () {
                $(this).find('.keytooltip').stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
            });
            $('.educoreres_key').mouseout(function() {
                $(this).find('.keytooltip').fadeOut(500);
            });

            return false;
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.educoreres_key').append('<div class="keyimg"></div><div class="keytooltip"><div class="keytooltiparrow"></div><div class="keytooltipinside"></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

            $('.webresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.webresource').attr('rel'));
            $('.pdfdocument .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.pdfdocument').attr('rel'));
            $('.worddocument .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.worddocument').attr('rel'));
            $('.videoresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.videoresource').attr('rel'));
            $('.webinarresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.webinarresource').attr('rel'));
            $('.powerpointresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.powerpointresource').attr('rel'));

            keyToolTip();
        });
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="eduresourceskeys">
            <div class="educoreres_key_label">Resources Key:</div>

            <div class="educoreres_key webresource" rel="Web Resource"></div>
            <div class="educoreres_key pdfdocument" rel="PDF Document"></div>
            <div class="educoreres_key worddocument" rel="Word Document"></div>
            <div class="educoreres_key videoresource" rel="Video Resource"></div>
            <div class="educoreres_key webinarresource" rel="Webinar Resource"></div>
            <div class="educoreres_key powerpointresource" rel="PowerPoint Resource"></div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.eduresourceskeys {
margin: 15px 0 0 45px;
}
div.educoreres_key_label {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
    color: #414141;
    font-family: 'HelveticaLTStdRegular', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 32px;
    }
div.educoreres_key {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 43px;
    height: 34px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    div.educoreres_key.webresource {}
    div.educoreres_key.pdfdocument {}
    div.educoreres_key.worddocument {}
    div.educoreres_key.videoresource {}
    div.educoreres_key.webinarresource {}
    div.educoreres_key.powerpointresource {}

        div.educoreres_key div.keyimg {
            width: 43px;
            height: 34px;
            }

        div.educoreres_key.webresource div.keyimg           { background: url("../img/icon_media_html_page.png") 0 0 no-repeat; }
        div.educoreres_key.pdfdocument div.keyimg           { background: url("../img/icon_media_pdf.png") 0 0 no-repeat; }
        div.educoreres_key.worddocument div.keyimg          { background: url("../img/icon_media_word_doc.png") 0 0 no-repeat; }
        div.educoreres_key.videoresource div.keyimg         { background: url("../img/icon_media_video.png") 0 0 no-repeat; }
        div.educoreres_key.webinarresource div.keyimg       { background: url("../img/icon_media_html_page.png") 0 0 no-repeat; }
        div.educoreres_key.powerpointresource div.keyimg    { background: url("../img/icon_media_powerpoint.png") 0 0 no-repeat; }

    div.keytooltip {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 20;
        margin: 0 0 0 -72px;
        display: none;
        width: 140px;
        border: 2px solid #1e5a7a;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);

        -webkit-border-radius:  4px;
        -moz-border-radius:     4px;
        border-radius:          4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
        box-shadow:         0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
        }
        div.keytooltipinside {
            position: relative;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #131313;
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            }
            div.keytooltiparrow {
                position: absolute;
                top: -10px;
                left: 50%;
                margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
                width: 20px;
                height: 10px;
                background: url("../img/tooltip_arrow.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
                }
```

Comment: Does `.parent()` work for you?

Comment: I have attempted to answer your question. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Mic1780, it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I was taking was wrong. Instead, I had to use

`$('parent item').each(function(){});`

I replaced the following in my original post:

```
        $('.webresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.webresource').attr('rel'));
        $('.pdfdocument .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.pdfdocument').attr('rel'));
        $('.worddocument .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.worddocument').attr('rel'));
        $('.videoresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.videoresource').attr('rel'));
        $('.webinarresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.webinarresource').attr('rel'));
        $('.powerpointresource .keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key.powerpointresource').attr('rel'));
```

With:

```
        $('.educoreres_key').each(function(){
            $(this).find('.keytooltipinside').append($(this).attr('rel'));
        });
```

And in case anyone is ever interested, I converted the above jQuery into a usable plugin. The plugin is simple, but it does the trick. Along with this  plugin, you can use the markup and CSS listed in the OP. The plugin is very simple, but it works nicely for what I need. Thanks

```
    // Tooltip Plugin
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.keyTip = function () {

            $(this).mouseover(function () {
                $(this).find('.keytooltip').stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
            });

            $(this).mouseout(function () {
                $(this).find('.keytooltip').fadeOut(500);
            });

            // Tooltip
            $(this).append('<div class="keyimg"></div><div class="keytooltip"><div class="keytooltiparrow"></div><div class="keytooltipinside"></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

            $(this).each(function () {
                $(this).find('.keytooltipinside').append($(this).attr('rel'));
            });

        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to go to the parent element and use its attrbute, might i suggest you target the element you want, go to the parent and use the attribute like so:

```
$(<selector>).parent().attr('rel');
```

documentation on `.parent()` can be [found here](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: Hi Mic1780, sorry I didn't respond over the weekend. I did try what you said (I had done this before posting actually), but what is happening is that it adds the very first item's 'rel' to all items in the list, not the rel text of each parent item to each keytooltipinside. This is what I have now `$('.keytooltipinside').append($('.educoreres_key').attr('rel'));` That is without the parent() added. And with the parent() added, the only difference is that the keytooltipinside container css is broken: `$('.keytooltipinside').parent().append($('.educoreres_key').attr('rel'));`